# Custom image for dynamic island on iOS

Tags: ios, dynamic-island

My app is playing media on iOS and sets an album art on `[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo` when it does that. Unfortunately, this album art does not look too good on the dynamic island as its real estate is too small.

Is it possible to set a different image for the dynamic island? I considered the possibility to create a live activity that would allow me to customize that, however this seems an overkill solution, as the app doesn't need a live activity. The OS fills all of the media needs of the app.

Comment: Not currently, as the dynamic island just mirrors the album art in the live activity on the lock screen using the `[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo`.

Comment: Does it make sense to override using activities?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though if it's a good idea is really up to you. It really depends on how bad the album art looks and on how comfortable you are with SwiftUI and Widgets / Live Activities. If you think you're up to it, then I'd recommend you go for it.